# add new recorded to my table with current timestamp and new status

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to add new record to my table with same previous record just modify the timestamp to current timestamp and new status , my table look like :

[image]

my expectation results is :

[image]

Any idea how , thanks in advance .

Comment: Is the previous one always the one with the status of 3?

Comment: What is the real issue: insert the data from some table or get *latest* records?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . If you want to add a "4" to all the "3"s, then:

```
insert into t (doc_id, time_stamp, doc_num, doc_status, num_emp)
    select doc_id, sysdate, doc_num, 4, num_emp
    from t
    where doc_status = 3;
```

If you want the *next* `doc_status` for each `doc_id`, then you need to get the most recent one and add 1:

```
insert into t (doc_id, time_stamp, doc_num, doc_status, num_emp)
    select doc_id, sysdate, doc_num, doc_status + 1, num_emp
    from (select t.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by doc_id order by time_stamp desc) as seqnum
          from t
         ) t
    where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (
COLUMN1
COLUMN2
COLUMN3
) 
SELECT
COLUMN1
COLUMN2
'YOUR VALUE' AS COLUMN 3 
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE 'YOUR FILTER HERE'
```

in the filter you get only the two rows you need (with a IN clause on the iD, for example), and you can specifiy the valuen you want in the select list